# Exclude some nodes while creating graph from csv

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have two csv files, one containing two columns in source_node, destination_node format and second one having a list of nodes. Now I am trying to create a graph using the first file with

```
load csv with headers from "file:///C:/Users/neo4j_workspace/new_graph_db/import/sample_edges.csv" as table 
merge (a:Node{name:table.destination_node }) 
with table, a 
merge (b:Node{name:table.source_node}) 
with a, b 
merge (a)-[:relates]->(b)
```

But I want to create the nodes as well as relationships between nodes where both source and destination nodes are in the column of second csv. I tried using WHERE as

```
load csv with headers from "file:///C:/Users/neo4j_workspace/new_graph_db/import/sample_list.csv" as jobs_table 
with list 
load csv with headers from "file:///C:/Users/neo4j_workspace/new_graph_db/import/sample_edges.csv" as table 
with table, list 
merge(a:Node{name:table.destination_node }) 
with table, list, a 
merge (b:Node{name:table.source_node}) 
with list, a, b 
merge(a)-[:relates]->(b) 
where (a and b in list.nodenames)
```

but I came to know that where cannot be used with **merge**. I know that about CASE, but I am not able to form a proper query using that. My db is empty to start with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the approach you're attempting, the query will create a cartesian product between all rows of your first CSV and all rows of your second CSV. This approach will perform poorly.

Instead, I'd recommend processing each file separately, first by creating all your nodes from the first CSV, then (after adding an index on :Node(name) if it isn't there already) processing the second CSV, matching to each node on the line by name and merging the relationship.

Comment: Thanks. I did the same thing, I realized it afterwards.